# The custom marker of the lightningchart doesn't work properly

Tags: lightningchart

I am using the marker from [current example](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0702-customCursor.html) but with vertical oriented chart and a few my upgrades. So my problem that in case of vertical chart the labels and values of variables isn't shown. But the same logic is properly works with horizontal oriented chart.

```
private createCustomMarker(): void {
  if (!this.seriesInstances.length) return;

  const resultTable: UIElementColumn<UIBackground> = this.chartInstance
    .addUIElement(UILayoutBuilders.Column, {
      x: this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisX(),
      y: this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisY()
    })
    .setMouseInteractions(false)
    .setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftCenter)
    .setMargin(5);

  const datetimeRow: UITextBox<UIBackground> = resultTable
    .addElement(UILayoutBuilders.Row)
    .addElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox);

  const rowsY: UITextBox<UIBackground>[] = this.seriesInstances
    .map((el: ISeriesInstance, i: number) => {
      return resultTable
        .addElement(UILayoutBuilders.Row)
        .addElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox)
        .setTextFillStyle(this.seriesInstances[i].instance.getStrokeStyle().getFillStyle());
    });

  const tick: CustomTick = (this.isAppearanceHorizontal ? this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisX() : this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisY())
    .addCustomTick()
    .setAllocatesAxisSpace(false)
    .disposeMarker();

  // Hide custom cursor components initially.
  resultTable.dispose();
  tick.dispose();

  this.chartInstance.onSeriesBackgroundMouseMove((_: ChartXY<PointMarker, UIBackground>, event: MouseEvent): void => {
    const mouseLocationClient: { x: number; y: number } = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };

    const mouseLocationEngine: Point = this.chartInstance.engine.clientLocation2Engine(
      mouseLocationClient.x,
      mouseLocationClient.y
    );

    // Translate mouse location to LCJS coordinate system for solving data points from series, and translating to Axes.
    // Translate mouse location to Axis.
    const mouseLocationAxis: Point = translatePoint(
      mouseLocationEngine,
      this.chartInstance.engine.scale,
      this.seriesInstances[0].instance.scale
    );

    // Solve the nearest data point to the mouse on each series.
    const nearestDataPoints: CursorPoint<Series2D>[] = this.seriesInstances.map((el: ISeriesInstance) => {
      return el.instance.solveNearestFromScreen(mouseLocationEngine) // on this line the most of elements have undefined, but data for it exists and poits are near beetween each other
    });

    // console.log(nearestDataPoints);

    // Find the nearest solved data point to the mouse.
    const nearestPoint: CursorPoint<Series2D> = nearestDataPoints.reduce((prev: CursorPoint<Series2D>, curr: CursorPoint<Series2D>) => {
      if (!prev) return curr;
      if (!curr) return prev;

      if (this.isAppearanceHorizontal) {
        return Math.abs(mouseLocationAxis.y - curr.location.y) < Math.abs(mouseLocationAxis.y - prev.location.y) ? curr : prev;
      } else {
        return Math.abs(mouseLocationAxis.x - curr.location.x) < Math.abs(mouseLocationAxis.x - prev.location.x) ? curr : prev
      }

    });

    if (nearestPoint) {
      // Set custom cursor location.
      resultTable.setPosition({
        x: mouseLocationAxis.x,
        y: mouseLocationAxis.y,
      });


      // Change origin of result table based on cursor location.
      let resultTableOrigin;
      const yScale: number = this.chartInstance.engine.scale.y.getInnerInterval();
      const isResultTableOriginXRight: boolean = mouseLocationEngine.x > this.chartInstance.engine.scale.x.getInnerInterval() / 2;
      if (mouseLocationEngine.y > yScale - (yScale / 100 * 30)) { // mouseLocationEngine.y > yScale - 30%
        resultTableOrigin = isResultTableOriginXRight ? UIOrigins.RightTop : UIOrigins.LeftTop;
      } else if (mouseLocationEngine.y < yScale / 100 * 30) { // mouseLocationEngine.y > 30% of yScale
        resultTableOrigin = isResultTableOriginXRight ? UIOrigins.RightBottom : UIOrigins.LeftBottom;
      } else {
        resultTableOrigin = isResultTableOriginXRight ? UIOrigins.RightCenter : UIOrigins.LeftCenter;
      }

      resultTable.setOrigin(resultTableOrigin);

      // Format result table text.
      const datetimeValue = this.isAppearanceHorizontal
        ? this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisX().formatValue(nearestPoint.location.x)
        : this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisY().formatValue(nearestPoint.location.y)
      datetimeRow.setText(`${datetimeValue}`);
      rowsY.map((rowY: UITextBox<UIBackground>, i: number) => {
        // this.seriesInstances[i].instance.isDisposed() ? rowY.dispose() : rowY.restore(); after this line labels of the table is low font contrast
        if (nearestDataPoints[i]?.location) {
          const foundSeries = chain(this.track.series)
            .flatMap()
            .value()[i]

          const value: string = this.isAppearanceHorizontal
            ? this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisY().formatValue(nearestDataPoints[i].location.y)
            : this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisX().formatValue(nearestDataPoints[i].location.x)

          rowY.setText(`${this.seriesInstances[i].instance.getName()}: ${value} ${foundSeries.unit}`) // probleblem on this line
        }
      });

      tick.setValue(
        this.isAppearanceHorizontal
          ? nearestPoint.location.x
          : nearestPoint.location.y
      );

      resultTable.restore();
      tick.restore();
    } else {
      resultTable.dispose();
      tick.dispose();
    }
  });

  this.chartInstance.onSeriesBackgroundMouseLeave(() => {
    resultTable.dispose();
    tick.dispose();
  });

  this.chartInstance.onSeriesBackgroundMouseDragStart(() => {
    resultTable.dispose();
    tick.dispose();
  });
}
```

I want to understand why almost the same code don't work on vertical oriented chart, but on horizontal works good.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem; what is the expected behaviour and what are you currently receiving with this code? Vertical chart meaning that cursor solving is done across Y plane rather than X? And the problem is that the cursor is not visible at all, or?

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/lineseries.html#setcursorsolvebasis

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen thanks for the answer, I've already found the problem... this link was helpful form me https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0504-dashboard2chs1000pps.html?theme=lightNew&page-theme=light and the my wrong was that I skipped current lines

dataPattern: {pattern: 'RegressiveY', regularProgressiveStep: true} and setCursorSolveBasis('nearest-y') on series create